# How can i use: driver.find_element_by_id but do not use: driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i use: driver.find_element_by_id
but do not use: driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
in selenium with python to find element

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium
# driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(3)
e_user = driver.find_element_by_id('orangeForm-email')
e_pass = driver.find_element_by_id('orangeForm-pass')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below if you want to get rid of  `driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')` this line

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\pathto\\my\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

***OR***

You can use WebDriver Manager API. -It downloads the driver.exe to your `/m2/repository/webdriver folder(while using Maven)`. It also automatically checks your browser version and download the matching version of driver.exe.

To use `Webdriver Manager AP`I, Include below lines in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>

<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>

<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>

<version>3.6.2</version>

<scope>test</scope>

</dependency>
```

*Then in your code just call this line before initialing the `Webdriver` object:*

```
//Call any of the line based on which browser you are using.

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.operadriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.phantomjs().setup();

WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
```

1- So you can eliminate the *downloading the driver binaries manually* and placing in the location

2- Below line of code also needs to be removed:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to your driver location");
```

*If this does not answer your question, so please provide the more detail to understand.*

Comment: @Aloxo, Please accept the answer if this has resolved your problem.